# Error QAbstractSocket while installing MQTT in QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, build, installation, mqtt

I am trying to build and install QMqtt for QT C++ in Ubuntu. I did the following commands but getting error.

```
git clone https://github.com/qt/qtmqtt.git
mkdir qtmqtt-build
cd qtmqtt-build
qmake ../qtmqtt/qtmqtt.pro
```

Then after enter command

```
make
```

I got an error

```
/home/atn/qtmqtt/src/mqtt/qmqttconnection.cpp:163:39: error: ‘errorOccurred’ is not a member of ‘QAbstractSocket’
163 |     connect(socket, &QAbstractSocket::errorOccurred, this, &QMqttConnection::transportError);
make[2]: *** [Makefile:639: .obj/qmqttconnection.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/atn/qt-build/src/mqtt'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:47: sub-mqtt-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/atn/qt-build/src'
make: *** [Makefile:49: sub-src-make_first] Error 2
```

I am also tried build and install from QtCreator but got the same error.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I failed to find `QAbstractSocket::errorOccurred()` function (signal) as well. Looks like an error in MQTT sources.

Comment: what is the output of `qmake -v`?

Comment: I tried to uninstall Qt5 and then install it again. Now when I run qmake -v, the result is /usr/bin/qmake: 12: exec: /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake: not found

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm having a similar issue at the moment and it would be nice to know if you got it working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After trying with current branch and still got error. I try another branch.

```
git clone https://github.com/qt/qtmqtt.git --branch 15.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no errorOccured function in [QAbstractSocket](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html) class, maybe authors have forget to commit some helper overloads...
Anyway there is [QAbstractSocket::error](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#error-1), but [QAbstractSocket::error](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#error-1) signal is overloaded, so to connect to this signal using function pointer you need to use [QOverload](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload) for it.

open file [src/mqtt/qmqttconnection.cpp](https://github.com/qt/qtmqtt/blob/dev/src/mqtt/qmqttconnection.cpp)

find:

```
connect(socket, &QAbstractSocket::errorOccurred, this, &QMqttConnection::transportError);
```

and change it to:

```
connect(socket, QOverload<QAbstractSocket::SocketError>::of(&QAbstractSocket::error), this, &QMqttConnection::transportError);
```

Comment: Thank you very much but now I got another error:
/home/atn/qtmqtt/src/mqtt/qmqttclient_p.h:49:10: fatal error: private/qobject_p.h: No such file or directory
   49 | #include <private/qobject_p.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Comment: @AnhTu Make sure that you are running the right qmake command. If you have error like private/qobject_p.h not found you are probably using the wrong qmake. In my case right qmake path is /opt/Qt/5.12.3/gcc_64/bin/qmake
Remove everything with rm -r * before running qmake from different path

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the private headers which are in qtbase5-private-dev:

```
sudo apt install qtbase5-private-dev
```